# Parse background job not saving the objects

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I have written parse cloud job in main.js and am getting the data from external site using rest api and trying to save the data as parse objects, in the logs i see the loop running but only three objects are being saved every time i run the background job.

There are no errors, the job status is success every time. I have tried several times, the result is same. Could not find relevant docs or i might be something here. Are there any limitations on how many objects are saved and how do i make sure the objects are saved as i don't see any errors.

Edit: code - url is modified

```
Parse.Cloud.job("costCenterFeedJob", function(request, status) {
var auth = 'c2tvdG012313AjJA==';
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'https://xxxx.xxxx?format=json',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+ auth 
  },
  success: function(httpResponse) {
   // console.log(httpResponse.text);
    console.log(httpResponse.data);

    var response = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
    var costCenters =  response.Report_Entry;
    console.log('json parse done');
    var WDCostCenter =  Parse.Object.extend("WDCostCenter");
    console.log(response.Report_Entry.length +'----');    
    var costCenter = null;   
    for(i=0; i<response.Report_Entry.length; i++) {
    costCenter = new WDCostCenter();
    costCenter.set("Name", response.Report_Entry[i].CostCenter);
    costCenter.set("RefID", response.Report_Entry[i].CostCenter_Workday_ID);
    costCenter.set("InActiveStatus", response.Report_Entry[i].InActive_Status);
    costCenter.save().then(function(message) {
    console.log("Success in Process :"+ i + message ); 
    }, function(error) {
       console.error("Error in Process :"+ i + error );
    });
    }
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
  }
}).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
  });

});
```

Edit : modified correct code - This works

```
Parse.Cloud.job("costCenterFeedJob", function(request, status) {
var auth = 'c2t12313321==';
 var promises = [];
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'https://xxxx.com?format=json',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+ auth 
  }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
   var response = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
    var costCenters =  response.Report_Entry;
    console.log('json parse done');
    var WDCostCenter =  Parse.Object.extend("WDCostCenter");
    console.log(response.Report_Entry.length +'----');
    var costCenter = null;
    //var promises = [];
    for(i=0; i<response.Report_Entry.length; i++) {
        costCenter = new WDCostCenter();
        costCenter.set("Name", response.Report_Entry[i].CostCenter);
        costCenter.set("RefID", response.Report_Entry[i].CostCenter_Workday_ID);
        costCenter.set("InActiveStatus", response.Report_Entry[i].InActive_Status);
        promises.push(costCenter.save().then(
          function(message) {
            console.log("Success in Process :"+ i + message );
          }, function(error) {
                console.error("Error in Process :"+ i + error );
          })
        );
    }
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    //console.success("httprequest  complented successfully.");
  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
  });
});
```

Comment: No specific limits, can you please paste relevant code?

Comment: Added the code in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job is terminated as soon as you call status.success/error. Since the .save() is asynchronous you need to make sure your saves are also in a promises chain.

You might need some more tweaking but change your loop to look something like this

```
var promises = [];
for(i=0; i<response.Report_Entry.length; i++) {
    costCenter = new WDCostCenter();
    costCenter.set("Name", response.Report_Entry[i].CostCenter);
    costCenter.set("RefID", response.Report_Entry[i].CostCenter_Workday_ID);
    costCenter.set("InActiveStatus", response.Report_Entry[i].InActive_Status);

    promises.push(costCenter.save().then(
        function(message) {
            console.log("Success in Process :"+ i + message ); 
        },
        function(error) {
            console.error("Error in Process :"+ i + error );
        })
    );
}

return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
```

Comment: still see the same behavior, i think the cloud job is getting completed before the httprequest is completed successfully as per the logs. "Migration completed successfully is getting printed first" which should have been printed last.                             I2014-08-14T20:57:45.451Z] v46: Ran job costCenterFeedJob with:
  Input: {}
  Result: Migration completed successfully.[object Object]
I2014-08-14T20:57:49.209Z] json parse done
I2014-08-14T20:57:49.284Z] 276----

Comment: Hank, i added the working code in my original post, the loop execution is done in then function instead of success. Thanks for pointing to the Promise concept :)

Comment: This solved my problem. And the `status.success/error` doesn't have to be there in the function. I simply removed these and it worked. Very helpful reply and Parse should put such comment in their document (or a more obvious place if they already did).